# Game of Pig-java

Tags: java

So I made quite a few changes to my code and now it complies, but I get the wrong totals and it always thinks Player 2 wins, even before it hits "20".   For some reason it isn't reading player 1 totalScore until after player 2 has rolled and then it does not calc player 2 turnTotal. When I made changes before, one thing would start working, but another would stop, so I took it back to where I began to have problems once it would compile.

```
 import java.util.*;

 public class Proj3Part1
 {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 int turnScore = 0;
 int totalScore = 0;
 int turnScore2 = 0;
 int totalScore2 = 0;
 final int WIN = 20;
 int dice = 0;
 int dice2 = 0;
 String input = "r";
 String input2 = "r";
 char repeat;

 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
 Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);

 Random randomNumbers = new Random();

 while(totalScore < WIN && totalScore2 < WIN)
 {
 //Player 1's turn

 do
  {
      dice = randomNumbers.nextInt(6) + 1;
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("You rolled: " + dice);

           if(dice == 1)
           {
               turnScore = 0;
               System.out.println("Turn over.");
               System.out.println("Player 1 total is " + totalScore);
               break;
           }
           else
           {         
              turnScore += dice;
              System.out.print("Player 1 turn total is " + turnScore + " ");
              System.out.print("Enter (r)oll or (s)top: ");
              input = keyboard.nextLine();
              repeat = input.charAt(0);


         if(repeat == 's')
         {
         System.out.println("Turn over.");
         System.out.print("Current score: Player 1 has " + totalScore);
         System.out.println(", Player 2 has " + totalScore2);
         break;

         }
      }
  }
 while(input.equalsIgnoreCase("r") || dice != 1); 
 {             

     totalScore += turnScore;
 }

  if(totalScore >= WIN)
  {
      System.out.println("Your total Score is " + totalScore);
      System.out.println("Player 1 wins!");

  }


  //player2's turn
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("It is Player 2's turn.");

 { do
  {
      dice2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(6) + 1; 
      System.out.println("Player 2 rolled: " + dice2);

      if(dice2 == 1)
        {
          turnScore2 = 0;
          System.out.print("Turn over");
          System.out.println("Player 2 total is " + totalScore2);
          break;             
        }
      else
      {
      turnScore2 += dice2;
      System.out.print("Player 2 total is " +turnScore2 + " ");
      System.out.print("Enter (r)oll or (s)top: ");
      input = keyboard.nextLine();
      repeat = input.charAt(0);


    if(repeat == 's')
        {
    System.out.println("Turn over");
    System.out.print("Current score: Player 1 has " + totalScore);
    System.out.println(", Player 2 has " + totalScore2);
    break;
        }
    }
}  
while(input2.equalsIgnoreCase("r") && dice != 1); {

    totalScore2 += turnScore2;

      }
 }
if(totalScore2 >= WIN);
  {
      System.out.println("Player 2 score is " + totalScore2 + "\n");
      System.out.println("Player 2 wins");
      break;
  }
 }


}
}
```

Comment: Better correct the indenting and formatting to make it more consistent.  Stackoverflow users tends to have a bias against people who can't be bothered to indent correctly.

Comment: What's the compiler error?

Comment: Please edit the content of this post and include what the actual error is.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a bias, or if it's more "why bother putting in the effort to help if the question poster doesn't put in the effort to make their code easy to read". Maybe they think that we're paid -- I wish we were, but we're not.

Comment: `while() { do { } while() do { } while() } }` unnggghhhhghghh

Comment: Danielle, Here is how to indent code properly: http://www.javaranch.com/styleLong.jsp

Comment: Thank you @EricLeschinski. I am taking my first programming class and the prof has never told us anything about formatting, so I just get the job done the only way I know how!

Comment: Stackoverflow expects quality far beyond CS 101 student output. What passes for acceptable in "Intro to CS" will get you banned here.  You broke almost all of the rules for posting a new question, the only reason you didn't get 5 downvotes here is because it's obvious you are a brand new programmer.  Next time, make an intuitive targeted specific title, and always ALWAYS show the compiler error you receive.  Read this link closely: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  and obey all those rules, and there is a chance you won't get banned over the course of your next few questions.

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in the loop for player2/computer's turn. It's in the first if-else loop, located in the else portion.

`input keyboard.nextLine();`

should be

`input = keyboard.nextLine();`

It works fine after correcting that error.

Also, pay close attention to the compilation errors, they will point you towards which lines are generating said error.

Revision:

I think this works the way you intended it to.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Proj3Part1
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     int turnScore = 0;
     int totalScore = 0;
     int turnScore2 = 0;
     int totalScore2 = 0;
     final int WIN = 20;
     int dice = 0;
     int dice2 = 0;
     String input = "r";
     String input2 = "r";
     char repeat;

     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);

     Random randomNumbers = new Random();

     while(totalScore < WIN && totalScore2 < WIN)
     {
       //Player 1's turn

      do
      {
          dice = randomNumbers.nextInt(6) + 1;
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println("You rolled: " + dice);

               if(dice == 1)
               {
                   turnScore = 0;
                   System.out.println("Turn over.");
                   System.out.println("Player 1 total is " + totalScore);
                   break;
               }
               else
               {      
                  turnScore = dice; //removed +=??? think it's only the value of dice roll? 
                                    //either way it's used to compute total, which would be redundant if not
                  totalScore +=turnScore; //added to compute totalScore before turn is over
                  System.out.print("Player 1 turn total is " + totalScore + " "); 
                  System.out.print("Enter (r)oll or (s)top: ");
                  input = keyboard.nextLine();
                  repeat = input.charAt(0);


                     if(repeat == 's')
                     {
                         System.out.println("Turn over.");
                         System.out.print("Current score: Player 1 has " + totalScore); //previously total wasn't computed
                         System.out.println(", Player 2 has " + totalScore2);
                         break;

                     }
               }
      }while(input.equalsIgnoreCase("r")); 


        //totalScore += turnScore; was removed + curly braces that seemed to attach it to the above while loop
        //it isn't needed due to totalScore now being calculated after dice is rolled when !=1(else portion)

      if(totalScore >= WIN)
      {
          System.out.println("Your total Score is " + totalScore);
          System.out.println("Player 1 wins!");
          break; //added to break the loop if player 1 wins
      }


      //player2's turn
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("It is Player 2's turn.");

      do
      {
          dice2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(6) + 1; 
          System.out.println("Player 2 rolled: " + dice2);

          if(dice2 == 1)
            {
              turnScore2 = 0;
              System.out.print("Turn over");
              System.out.println("Player 2 total is " + totalScore2);
              break;             
            }
          else
            {
              turnScore2 = dice2; //removed += ... same as for player 1's turn
              totalScore2 += turnScore2; //added totalScore2 calculations.
              System.out.print("Player 2 total is " +totalScore2 + " ");
              System.out.print("Enter (r)oll or (s)top: ");
              input = keyboard.nextLine();
              repeat = input.charAt(0);


              if(repeat == 's')
               {
                System.out.println("Turn over");
                System.out.print("Current score: Player 1 has " + totalScore);         
                System.out.println(", Player 2 has " + totalScore2);
                break;
              }
            }
    }  
    while(input2.equalsIgnoreCase("r")); //{ <- incorrect brace + fixed loop for dice2 !=1, then removed it :P since you already did a check inside the do-while loop

        //totalScore2 += turnScore2; removed, no longer is needed

          //}
     //} <- not needed nor is the brace that was infront of the do while loop.
    if(totalScore2 >= WIN) //removed semicolon since it ended the if statement before it's body
      {
          System.out.println("Player 2 score is " + totalScore2 + "\n");
          System.out.println("Player 2 wins");
          break;
      }

    if(totalScore>totalScore2) //added loops to check which score is higher and terminate
    {
      System.out.println("Player 1 Wins!");
      break;
    }else if(totalScore==totalScore2){
      System.out.println("It's a Tie!");
      break;
    }else if(totalScore<totalScore2){
      System.out.println("Player 2 Wins!");
      break;
    }
  }


 }
}
```

I also recommend installing an IDE such as [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/). An IDE would make your life much easier, especially with formatting and syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you! I have been playing around with the code since posting this and now have a completely new set of issues :-(

Comment: I posted my revised code with an explanation of the "new" problems. I made some changes and one thing would start working, but another would stop